# Understanding 'latent' output of princomp() in Matlab

Tags: pca, matlab

I have a feature vector containing 17 features. I need to take only features containing 98% variance. So I did principal component analysis (PCA) in Matlab like this:

```
[COEFF,SCORE,latent] = princomp(X);
cumsum(latent)./sum(latent)
```

and got this:

```
    0.9082
    0.9824
    0.9999
    0.9999
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    [...]
```

The first value `0.9082` indicates the variance value of the first principle component, is that correct?

Now if I need to select features containing 98% variance, do I select only those:

```
    0.9824
    0.9999
    0.9999
```

What does 1.0 mean? Does this mean 100% variance?

Comment: Aren't these cumulated frequencies rather than % variance accounted for by each component? If this is the case, your results suggest to consider the first two components.

Comment: i added pca code, do you mean i should take ->   0.9082 and
    0.9824 ?

Answer (score 5):

The eigenvalues are proportional to the explained variance. You have given us their cumulative sum, therefore we conclude the first two eigenvectors alone account for over 98% of the variance, per your requirement.

Comment: so then i should input the first two columns of the score vector into the classifier right ?

Comment: Assuming your "need to take only features containing 98% variance" (your problem description), you should retain only the first two principal components. By discarding the remainder, you are simplifying the problem. This is the point of PCA.

Comment: now i have one major problem, how do i know which of the 17 input features are the most significant ?

Comment: The ones with the greatest projection on the leading principal component. You can take the absolute value of their dot products.